# Deleted AutoProtect snapshots and can't boot VM's

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, snapshot

I've had 3 VM's running AutoProtect fine for several months but decided it was pointless and wanted to disable it.

I also simultaneously wanted to enable `Persistent Independent disk access`. I wasn't able to do this as it complained that `snapshots existed` and therefore I couldn't. So I deleted the snapshots from AutoProtect thinking that since it was disabled, they were useless but now I can't boot any of the 3 virtual machines.

I'm attempting to recover them using [R-Linux File Recovery](http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/) but even if I get the AutoProtect snapshots back, I still need to somehow delete them 'properly'. *Edit: This doesn't appear to be working - the only files I get back are 0 bytes.*

As per a few other answers I tried editing the `.vmx` file to point only to the `.vmdk` that is the main system but it still fails to boot and demands `x-00001.vmdk`.

Comment: Exactly what happens when you try to boot the VMs?  How did you delete the snapshots?

Comment: @jamesdlin It complains about a missing file sometimes specifically the one mentioned or sometimes just `file missing`. It then does not boot at all. I manually deleted the snapshots in their folder instead of through the VMware interface.

Comment: I'm sorry, but because you directly deleted the snapshots in the folder, you broke your VM.  You deleted the data instead of allowing VMware Workstation to merge the data into a single `.vmdk` file.  You probably should look into data recovery software.

Comment: That is what I suspected but thought I'd give this a try. IMO the most recent data ought to be in the primary `.vmdk` and only the prior AutoProtect snapshots should be saved externally to files. That's the way I assumed it worked.

Comment: Each `.vmdk` file for a snapshot stores the *changes* made since the previous snapshot, so if you deleted those, you can no longer reconstruct the most recent state of the VM's disk.

Answer (score 0):

Not in any way an ideal solution but I had to erase the VM's and recreate them using the `.vmdk` as a pre-existing drive which resulted in some loss of data but not much.